# TypeError: object() takes no parameters - python3

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am trying to work on some problem where I could use this code to learn how to implement Binary Search Tree, this code is based on http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/SearchTreeImplementation.html however there are come bugs in the original code, which I think should be fixed by doing the following.
Edited this code to remove a syntax error.

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls, args, kwargs)

    def __init__(self, key, val, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self

    def isRightChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.rightChild == self

    def isRoot(self):
        return not self.parent

    def isLeaf(self):
        return not(self.leftChild or self.rightChild)

    def hasAnyChildren(self):
        return self.leftChild or self.rightChild

    def hasBothChildren(self):
        return self.leftChild and self.rightChild

    def replaceNodeData(self, key, value, lc, rc):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = value
        self.leftChild = lc
        self.rightChild = rc
        if self.hasLeftChild():
            self.leftChild.parent = self
        if self.hasRightChild():
            self.rightChild.parent = self


class BinarySearchTree(TreeNode):
    def __init__(self):
        # self.root is refrence to TreeNode, which is root
        # of primary TreeNode
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def size(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.root.__iter__()

    def put(self, key, val):
        # checks if there is root
        # if there is a root, lets transverse along tree
        if self.root:
            self._put(key, val, self.root)
        else:
            # else if there is not root, lets set a root
            # which is a TreeNode instance
            self.root = super(BinarySearchTree, cls).__new__(key, val)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self, key, val, currentNode):

        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key, val, currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = super(BinarySearchTree, cls).__new__(
                    key, val, parent=currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key, val, currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = super(BinarySearchTree, cls).__new__(
                    key, val, parent=currentNode)

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.put(k, v)

    def get(self, key):
        if self.root:
            res = self._get(key, self.root)
            if res:
                return res.payload
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def _get(self, key, currentNode):
        if not currentNode:
            return None
        if key == currentNode.key:
            return currentNode
        if key < currentNode.key:
            return self._get(key, currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            return self._get(key, currentNode.rightChild)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # this method allows to access instance[index]
        # format.
        return self.get(key)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        """
        __contains__ overloads the 'in' operator
        allows us to do something simliar to
        if 'Northfield' in myZipTree:
            print("oom ya ya")
        """
        if self._get(key, self.root):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def delete(self, key):
        if self.size > 1:
            nodeToRemove = self._get(key, self.root)
            if nodeToRemove:
                self.remove(nodeToRemove)
                self.size = self.size - 1
            else:
                raise KeyError('Error, key was not found')
        elif self.size == 1 and self.root.key == key:
                self.root = None
                self.size = self.size - 1
        else:
            raise KeyError('Error, key was not found')

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.delete(key)

    def remove(self, currentNode):
        if currentNode.isLeaf():
            # current Leaf has only one child
            if currentNode == currentNode.parent.leftChild:
                currentNode.parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                currentNode.parent.rightChild = None

        elif currentNode.hasBothChildren():
            # interior
            succ = currentNode.findSuccessor()
            succ.spliceOut()
            currentNode.key = succ.key
            currentNode.payload = succ.payload

        else:
            # The node to be deleted has only one child.
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
                else:
                    # this is a root node, replace it's data with it's
                    # left children
                    self.replaceNodeData(
                        currentNode.leftChild.key,
                        currentNode.leftChild.value,
                        currentNode.leftChild,
                        currentNode.rightChild
                    )
            else:
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
                else:
                    # this is a root node, replace it's data with it's
                    # left children
                    self.replaceNodeData(
                        currentNode.leftChild.key,
                        currentNode.leftChild.value,
                        currentNode.leftChild,
                        currentNode.rightChild
                    )

    def __iter__(self):
        if self:
            if self.hasLeftChild():
                for elem in self.leftChiLd:
                    yield elem
            yield self.key
            if self.hasRightChild():
                for elem in self.rightChild:
                    yield elem

    def findSuccessor(self):
        succ = None
        if self.hasRightChild():
            succ = self.rightChild.findMin()
        else:
            if self.parent:
                if self.hasLeftChild():
                    succ = self.parent
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = None
                    succ = self.parent.findSuccessor()
                    self.parent.rightChild = self
        return self

    def findMin(self):
        if self.hasLeftChild():
            return self.leftChild.findMin()
        else:
            return self

    def spliceOut(self):
        if self.isLeaf():
            if self.isLeftChild():
                self.parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                self.parent.rightChild = None
        elif self.hasAnyChildren():
            if self.hasLeftChild():
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    self.parent.leftChild = self.leftChild
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = self.leftChild
                self.leftChild.parent = self.parent
            else:
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    self.parent.leftChild = self.rightChild
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = self.rightChild
                self.rightChild.parent = self.parent



mytree = BinarySearchTree()
mytree[17] = "17"
mytree[5] = "5"
mytree[35] = "35"
mytree[2] = "2"
mytree[11] = "11"
mytree[9] = "9"
mytree[16] = "16"
mytree[7] = "7"
mytree[29] = "29"
mytree[38] = "38"

del(mytree[5])
print(mytree[5])
print(mytree[7])
print(mytree.size)
```

however when I running the code I am getting the following error, I am not very good in OOPs concepts, any educationatory lessons will be appreciated.

```
# vaibhavchauhan @ startup001 in ~/Documents/Projects/interactivepython [19:17:01] C:1
$ python3 binarySearchTreeMod.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binarySearchTreeMod.py", line 248, in <module>
    mytree = BinarySearchTree()
  File "binarySearchTreeMod.py", line 3, in __new__
    return object.__new__(cls, args, kwargs)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to `object.__new__`. Those stars are important.

Comment: args is an empty list and kwargs is an empty dict, so when you unpack them with stars, you get nothing, as required. If you do not unpack them, you are passing in a list and a dict.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the `__new__` method?

Comment: Also, please make an effort to isolate the error a bit more... that's a lot of code to sift through.

Comment: I am trying to create a new object in `self.root = super(BinarySearchTree, cls).__new__(key, val)` as doing `self.root = super(BinarySearchTree, self).__init__(key, val)`would return a `None type` object which is not desirable. Please suggest a better approach if any, happy to learn and implement

Comment: I have answered your immediate question in my first two comments. Is there still a problem?

Answer (score -1):

That `__new__` method shouldn't be there. Just remove it. It has a particular purpose, but if you're just learning you shouldn't need it at all.

The `__new__` method is primarily used for subclassing immutable objects. That's not what you have, so you don't need it.

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) for more information.

Comment: If you do make a sweeping statement like that, explain your reasoning thoroughly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The answer is now sufficient to unblock him. The detailed information is in the documentation.

Comment: please look at my comment up above, which explains why I am using `__new__` in place of `__init__` please suggest better approach.

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan The root would be an instance held outside of the object that has a *None* value for the parent object.  Or you can just put a root object as another instance of the class. `self.root = BinarySearchTree()`.